# React - re-binding onClick prop of React <Button > component doesn't change onClick of contained button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I'm trying to re-bind the `onClick` attached to a `<button>`. The `<button>`, however, is actually inside a child component rendered by a UI widget called `<Button />`

So what I'm doing is:

```
<MyComponent>
   <.. arbitrary number of levels deep nesting>
      <Button onClick={foo} />
   </end nesting>
</MyComponent>
```

In `MyComponent`'s constructor, I search for `<Button>`, then bind/rebind the `<Button >`'s `onClick` to my new function '`bar`'.

I even correctly see the function `bar` as the new `onClick` prop of `<Button />` when inspecting in the console.

However, when I actually click the `<Button />` on the page, original `foo` always gets executed, not `bar`.

I have a suspicion it has to do with `foo` being tied to the actual `innerHTML` `button` inside `<Button />`, and I need to change that somehow, too. (But I don't want to do it in this kludgy way, if it is even possible)

How can I correctly rebind the `onClick` of `<Button />` inside `<MyComponent />`'s constructor (or any other function like `MyComponent.componentDidMount`)?

EDIT:

`MyComponent` is actually meant to be a reuseable widget, and I am traversing its props.children to find the button with type == 'submit'.  So, I am avoiding the solution of doing `React.Children.map((child) => {React.cloneElement( ...)))`, since there's some possibility that, theoretically, the button with type === 'submit' may be buried as many layers down as the user of the widget has nested.

Thanks

Comment: "I have a suspicion it has to do with foo being tied to the actual innerHTML button inside <Button />, and I need to change that somehow, too." What does the Button component look like?

Comment: The <Button> is the button in react-mdl (react material design lite), It looks like this when final rendered:  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--primary" type="submit" data-upgraded=",MaterialButton">Confirm</button>

Comment: Show your Button component not rendered